# SSIS Clear configuration variables values after package run / before saving

Tags: sql, variables, ssis

I have some SSIS packages that connect to an Oracle database. The connection parameters are stored in a SQL database and retrieved by using the Package Configuration tool.

My problem is that the variable that gets populated automatically by SSIS with the configuration string does not get emptied after the package is run. As a result, the value of the variable get saved in the source code when the package is saved. I DO NOT want to have this variable value saved in my source files.

Any idea on how to prevent this from happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your variable set to be an expression?

Comment: My variable is not set to be an expression. However the problem remains the same if I set it to be an expression.

Comment: Set as expression put in a placeholder variable then set the variable with a package configuration.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? I am not sure I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 5):

You can try setting the variable in a package configuration. The way you do this is simple.

First go to the top most layer of your package and right click on the empty space and select package configurations. Choose to add add. Give a location and name for the file and then click next.

Once you've done that choose the variable you want and set the value like this.

[image: Expression]

Now you're not storing the actual value in the package. Just the information for how to find it.

**EDIT:** I may not have been clear on this. This process will create a **completely separate file** that the package will look to  to get that expression. This way you don't have to store the expression or the value in the package itself. It just knows at run time to go look for that config file for any additional data.

**EDIT 2:** The package configuration will only overwrite when you execute the package in BIDS over Visual Studio. The reason this happens is because the package evaluates and then saves prior to run time. This does not happen when you are using SQL agent to run a package and therefore will not store the value or the expression in the source code. I hope I have clarified that for you.

Comment: Hi Zane, thanks for your answer. My problem is that my string still gets saved in the source code of my package.

Comment: I thought you didn't want the value saved?

Comment: That's my point. When I save my package, it retains the last value for each variable. I do NOT want that to happen

Comment: Exactly that's why you put a placeholder value like 0 or something as your expression in the package. Then create this package config and it will replace the 0 with expression and runtime and pass the appropriate variable without saving it in the package.

Comment: I got your point, but in this case the expression also gets saved in my source code

Comment: So you don't want the expression itself to be anywhere in the code either?

Comment: Correct, I want it to be stored in a separate file or on a SQL server. My problem is that the connection variable retains the information after the package has been run in debug mode. And if you save the package, you also save this string in the source code.

Comment: I understand, Zane. But once the variable gets loaded locally with the data from the file/SQL server it never gets cleared. Then if I save my package it will also store the string in the source code.

Comment: @user3446994 I believe that only happens if you are executing in BIDS. Trying running it through SQL agent and it shouldn't overwrite that.

Comment: Can't you just cleat it out before you save the file from BIDS?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: but then you have to remember to clear it out every time you save it. It's very easy for that to be missed and the sensitive information to be saved.

Comment: Its probably a considerable change but if you use 'externally identified' security (similar to trusted authentication in sql server) then you don't need to save a password anywhere - it uses the windows account for authentication